# Why does the windows api scrollbars not respond?

Tags: c, winapi, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a scrollable `child-window` within a window. The child-window is supposed to have `scrollbars`; the scrollbars appear but are totally unresponsive. Window creation code:

```
// "mainwindow" is the handle of the main application window.
HWND wnd = CreateWindow(WC_STATIC, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL,
    10, 100, 300, 300, mainwindow, NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);

SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
si.nMax = 800;

SetScrollInfo(g_wnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
```

I've set a custom `WNDPROC` for the new `child-window`, but no scrolling-messages arrive. I've found numerous examples on the internet, but none of them either work or are about using `scrollbars` in child-windows.

Comment: Perhaps because you don't have enough content in the window to need to scroll? There's no need for a responsive (enabled) scrollbar (and no need for scrollbar messages) when there is no scrollable content.

Comment: I've put another subwindow with a size of `800x800` pixel within the scrolling area, but still no luck.

Comment: I can't see what you've done from here, and there's no indication that you've done so. How can I reproduce the problem?

Comment: A STATIC control has no meaningful scrolling implementation.  You'd have to subclass it to alter its behavior.  After which you are unlikely to actually use much of any of its standard behavior.  Get ahead by just creating your own window class.

Comment: Thank you @Hans Passant, I've successfully created my scrollable child-window now using a custom windows class. I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out, a scrollable child-window needs its own windows class.

Example code:

```
HWND create_scroll_window(HWND parent)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyScrollWinClass");

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) return 0;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(_T("MyScrollWinClass"), _T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL, 20, 20,
    300, 300, parent, NULL, wcex.hInstance, NULL);

    return hWnd;
}
```

Comment: You can improve the code by using `__ImageBase` pseudo linker variable instead of calling `GetModuleHandle(0)` (see [Accessing the current module's HINSTANCE from a static library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx)). This ensures that the code will continue to work when compiled into a DLL.

Comment: A "correct answer" would probably include showing the `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL` handlers in the wndproc, since others finding this question may assume that simply adding a window class is enough.

Comment: Perhaps a link to the entries of Raymond's scrollbar series? (They're among the first on the blog so...)